# getTransaction returns null for some pendingTransactions subscribe results

Tags: web3js, json-rpc

I have subscribed to ETH pendingTransactions in mainnet.
I am doing getTransaction for each received pendingTransaction like below.

```
web3.eth.subscribe('pendingTransactions', function(error, txnid) {
    if (txnid) {
        web3.eth.getTransaction(txnid, function(err, txn) {
            if (!err) {
                console.log(txn);
            }
            else
                console.log(err);
        });
    }
    else
        console.log(error);
});
```

My issue is, I am getting txn=null for some of the txnid. And if I try after some time, I get proper response.

Is there any other method to listen all new incoming transactions and `getTransaction` for them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question is two years old by now. But I wanted to answer, because the original answer is not the correct explanation. As the comment says, Geth does *not* require transactions be mined before making them available on the `getTransaction()` API.

Rather, the issue is that Geth's txPool consistency model is not full read-after-write. When a tx hash is published to the subscriber, it is not guaranteed to be processed for serving on the API. If you try to fetch `getTransaction()` immediately after, you may hit a race condition and get a null (i.e. not found) result.

The solution isn't to wait for the next block to be mined, it's to retry in a short interval. Geth does support eventual consistency, typically on the scale of milliseconds, so you will see it well before the next block.

Comment: 1 year later;)
Treating the race condition fix some of these, others are "zombies" (nonce double/replacement, tx failing, low gas, etc) waiting to get purged (accounting for a lot of those null's nowadays)

Answer (score 2):

when transaction is just submitted into network, its still pending, you need to wait for it to be mined then only the `web3.eth.getTransaction` return correct value, put in in the loop with settimeout.

Comment: This is not correct, getTransaction returns transaction's data even when they are pending, some fields like block will be missing in that case.